# Chisel3 REPL Vec assignment into module only works after eval

Tags: chisel, digital-logic

If we run the following Chisel3 code

```scala
class Controller extends Module {

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
  })
  val sff = Module(new SFF)

  val frame: Vec[UInt] = Reg(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, Integer32Bit))
  for(i <- 0 until ProcedureSpaceSize)
    frame(i) := 99.U

  sff.io.inputDataVector := frame
}

class SFF extends Module {

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val inputDataVector: Vec[UInt] = Input(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, Integer32Bit))
  })

}
```

in REPL debug mode. First do

```
reset;step

peek sff.io_inputDataVector_0;peek sff.io_inputDataVector_1;peek sff.io_inputDataVector_2
```

The REPL returns

```
Error: exception Error: getValue(sff.io_inputDataVector_0) returns value not found
Error: exception Error: getValue(sff.io_inputDataVector_1) returns value not found
Error: exception Error: getValue(sff.io_inputDataVector_2) returns value not found
```

Then do

```
eval sff.io_inputDataVector_0
```

which will be a success, yielding

```
...
resolve dependencies
  evaluate     sff.io_inputDataVector_0 <= frame_0
  evaluated    sff.io_inputDataVector_0 <= 99.U<32>
```

Then perform the above peek again

```
peek sff.io_inputDataVector_0;peek sff.io_inputDataVector_1;peek sff.io_inputDataVector_2;
```

This time, it returns

```
peek sff.io_inputDataVector_0  99
peek sff.io_inputDataVector_1  99
peek sff.io_inputDataVector_2  99
```

which is more expected.

Why does the REPL act in this way? Or was there something I missed? Thanks!

*`chisel-iotesters` is in version `1.4.2`, and `chiseltest` is in version `0.2.2`. Both should be the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firrtl interpreter REPL does not necessarily compute or store values that on a branch of a `mux` that is not used. This can lead to problems noted above like

`Error: exception Error: getValue(sff.io_inputDataVector_0) returns value not found`.

`eval` can be used to force unused branches to be evaluated anyway. The REPL is an experimental feature that has not had a lot of use.

[treadle](https://github.com/freechipsproject/treadle) is the more modern chisel scala-based simulator. It is better supported and faster than the interpreter. It has a REPL of its own, but does not have an `executeFirrtlRepl` equivalent.

It must be run from the command line via the ./treadle.sh script in the root directory. One can also run `sbt assembly` to create a much faster launching jar that is placed in utils/bin. This REPL also has not been used a lot but I am interested on feedback that will make it better and easier to use.

Comment: Treadle works great. Thanks! The only comment I have is that I couldn't initiate the REPL as easily as the firrtlREPL, and I have to pass the location of a *.fir file, which I must also compile first.

Comment: Added a treadle issue https://github.com/freechipsproject/treadle/issues/242 to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you are seeing is that all your wires are being eliminated due to dead code elimination. There are a couple of things you should try to fix this.

- Make sure you have meaningful connections of your wires. Hardware that does not ultimately affect an output is likely to get eliminated. In your example you do not have anything driving a top level output
- You probably need your circuit to compute something with those registers. If the registers are initialized to 99 then constant propagation will likely eliminate them. I'm not sure what you are trying to get the circuit to do so it is hard to make a specific recommendation.

If you get the above done I think the repl will work as expected. I do have a question about which repl you are using (there are two: firrtl-interpreter and treadle) I recommend using the latter. It is more modern and better supported. It also has two commands that would be useful

- `show lofirrtl` will show you the lowered firrtl, this is how you can see that lots of stuff from the high firrtl emitted by chisel3 has been changed.
- `symbol .` shows you all symbols in circuit (`.` is a regex that matches everything.

Here is a somewhat random edit of your circuit that drives and output based on your `frame` `Vec`. This circuit will generate firrtl that will not eliminated the wires you are trying to see.

```
class Controller extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val out = Output(UInt(32.W))
  })
  val sff = Module(new SFF)

  val frame: Vec[UInt] = Reg(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, Integer32Bit))
  when(reset.asBool()) {
    for (i <- 0 until ProcedureSpaceSize) {
      frame(i) := 99.U
    }
  }
  frame.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (element, index) => element := element + index.U }
  sff.io.inputDataVector := frame
  io.out := sff.io.outputDataVector.reduce(_ + _)

}

class SFF extends Module {

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val inputDataVector: Vec[UInt] = Input(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, Integer32Bit))
    val outputDataVector: Vec[UInt] = Output(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, Integer32Bit))
  })

  io.outputDataVector <> io.inputDataVector
}
```

Comment: I am using firrtlREPL. The thing is, I didn't show my entire actual code, so I am not sure this is the same problem because I certainly used all my registers and wires in my original code. Is there any way I could just turn off all optimization in firrtlREPL such that the REPL the result is a faithful reflection of my circuit?

Comment: The command line flag --no-dce should help here. You would need to pass it to your invocation of the repl.

Comment: I tried both "--no-dce" as well as "--compiler mverilog" on the above small circuit. It produces the same invalid result when peeking; it doesn't seem like it has to do with compiler optimization. The exact problem in my larger circuit is, strangely, the last two units in the vector port show results when peeked, but the first two units are shown to be invalid (in a vector of length four). If I manually eval any of the four units, all the results will flip to become correct.

Comment: Hmm, can you provide a bit more complete example. Also can you describe how you are launching the repl, it could matter in how the command line arguments are processed. I am not sure what's going on but it should be fixable.

Comment: I posted the complete code here https://pastebin.com/x0G70EGK with re-enactment instructions here https://pastebin.com/9nhR3QtU. A sample REPL class is here https://pastebin.com/2J65DUEJ. I apologize if it's a bit messy. It's the best I could have done with regard to logistics.

Comment: Your example code seems fine. Short story, I think the firrllRepl is quirky. It does not necessarily evaluate state on branches of muxes that are not used. `eval` seems to override this. firrtlRepl is going to be deprecated. Use treadle instead. but you will have to clone treadle, it doesn't have an executeFirrtlRepl convenience function, but does have launch script in its root dir. (doing `sbt assembly` will make a jar that starts up much faster). treadle does use DCE by default but that can be overridden on command line. Sorry this was so convoluted